# JAX RS MessageBodyWriter not found for media type=application/json

Tags: java, rest, jax-rs

I am creating Rest client using JAX RS Jersey 2. The client works but only in my IDE (IntellIJ IDEA), when I build it with Maven, using maven-assembly-plugin and run the jar it doesn't work anymore.

I get MessageBodyWriter not found for media type=application/json error.

I have tried adding more dependencies that people suggested in other posts but I don't think a dependency is a problem since it runs in the IDE.

Here is the code that throws the exception

```
return client.target(uri)
        .request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
        .post(Entity.entity(transactions.get(0), MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
```

After debugging, when I replace transactions.get(0) with an empty string "", it works.

Here is the pom.xml for maven

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>11</source>
                <target>11</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <mainClass>SequencerControllers</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sparkjava</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
        <version>2.25.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
        <version>2.25.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.21</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Am i missing something? Really bothers me that it runs in the IDE but not when built with Maven since I build it with dependencies.

Comment: How was this issue resolved ? I added below recommended jar still I see same issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check if you have class `com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.json.JacksonJsonProvider` in your resulting JAR. If not, add following dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs-json-provider</artifactId>
    <version>2.10.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I have added above jar , and I see JacksonJsonProvider class in my fat jar . still I see same issue ? could you please help if any other thoughts ?

Comment: @santoshjk: It is not clear what problem exactly you have. Are you sure you have the same problem as described above? The OP creates a *single* JAR with dependencies. Are you sure you do the same? The OP is launching the application using a *single* JAR. Are you sure you do the same? If you do the same, then it doesn't matter what you have in your classpath. That's why I'd suggest you to ask a question and describe in details what exactly are you doing and what exactly the problem is. Then you will get answers that can help you.

Comment: Yes I am have same scenerio . I am executing single jar with dependencies, and  executing with same jar.

Comment: @santoshjk: Then describe the contents of the JAR. How many JARs it contains? Does it contains any other "jackson" JARs? Does it contains the jackson-jaxrs-json-provider JAR? What command line you use to launch the application?

Answer (score 1):

there's an ordering issue as the Jackson and Jackson / jersey jars don't play well in an "uber" assembly jar. This is because they have same-named files in their individual jars that contain different values.

The assembly plugin will pick one version as the "winner" that gets included in the uber jar. The losing duplicate will not be included and in your case, you are likely getting the wrong copy included in your uber jar.

To fix this, make sure that these 2 entries are moved to the top of the maven dependencies list

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
  <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
  <version>${jersey-version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs</groupId>
  <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs-json-provider</artifactId>
  <version>${jackson-version}</version>
</dependency>
```

I also moved this one at the bottom of the dependencies:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
  <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
  <version>${jackson-version}</version>
</dependency>
```

That combination seemed to fix the uber jar issue in my situation.